# MATLAB-like array indexing with Numpy

Tags: matlab, numpy, python-3.x

In both MATLAB and Numpy, arrays can be indexed by arrays. However, the behavior is different. Let me explain this by an example.

MATLAB:

```
>> A = rand(5,5)

A =

    0.1622    0.6020    0.4505    0.8258    0.1067
    0.7943    0.2630    0.0838    0.5383    0.9619
    0.3112    0.6541    0.2290    0.9961    0.0046
    0.5285    0.6892    0.9133    0.0782    0.7749
    0.1656    0.7482    0.1524    0.4427    0.8173

>> A([1,3,5],[1,3,5])

ans =

    0.1622    0.4505    0.1067
    0.3112    0.2290    0.0046
    0.1656    0.1524    0.8173
```

Numpy:

```
In [2]: A = arange(25).reshape((5,5))

In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [6]: A[[0,2,4], [0,2,4]]
Out[6]: array([ 0, 12, 24])
```

In words: MATLAB selects rows and columns, Numpy "zips" the two index arrays and uses the tuples to point to entries.

How can I get the MATLAB behavior with Numpy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this:

```
A[[0,2,4],:][:,[0,2,4]]
```

which will give the MATLAB-like result you want.

It's worth being aware that, rather inconsistently, if you use slices for indexing then you get MATLAB-like results without any such hackery:

```
>>> A[1:3,1:3]
array([[ 6, 7],
       [11,12]])
```

In numpy, unlike MATLAB, `1:3` is not just an abbreviation for `[1,2]` or anything of the kind. (At which point I feel obliged to mention something you surely know already, namely that Python's `1:3` is kinda like `[1,2]` whereas MATLAB's is kinda like `[1,2,3]`: the right-hand endpoint is included in MATLAB and excluded in Python.)

Comment: This is actually quite inefficient. It requires creating a temporary array in memory that can be quite large depending on the size of the arrays you're working with. There are several more efficient ways to do this, including using the ix_ helper function.

Comment: Yup, all correct. On the other hand, the thing constructed by `ix_` is also quite big, albeit temporary. I did some timing experiments for a 5x5 array as in the original question, with the following results. `[,:][:,]` is about 25% faster than `[ix_()]`, but if you're using the same indexes every time then constructing an indexing array *once* with `ix_` and reusing it is about 10x faster -- though of course you then pay a cost in memory usage.

Comment: np.ix_, in most cases, only uses a trivial amount of memory because it returns views of it's arguments. Also np.ix_ is a constant time operation while A[I1, :][:, I2] is ~ n^2 in both time and memory usage. But if you really need that 25% performance boost on your 5x5 array, you got to do what you got to do.

Comment: You're right about `ix_` using no memory to speak of; I hadn't been aware of that. Thanks. If you're suggesting that occasions when you're indexing a small array with unpredictable sets of indices and care about every last microsecond are rare, then of course I agree! The `ix_` approach will usually be better if you care about performance.

Comment: +1 for the final explanation on how to get correct Matlab-like indexing in numpy using `A[[0,2,4],:][:,[0,2,4]]`
Thanks!

Comment: Just want to add.. you cannot SET values using this approach. Rather user @User2593047 his method

Answer (score 20):

You can use the helper function [`numpy.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to get the Matlab behaviour:

```
from numpy import ix_
A[ ix_( [0,2,4], [0,2,4] ) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The efficient way to do this with numpy is to reshape your index array to match the axes they are indexing i.e.

```
In [103]: a=numpy.arange(100).reshape(10,10)

In [104]: a
Out[104]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
   [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
   [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
   [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
   [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
   [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
   [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
   [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])

In [105]: x=numpy.array([3,6,9])

In [106]: y=numpy.array([2,7,8])

In [107]: a[x[:,numpy.newaxis],y[numpy.newaxis,:]]
Out[107]: 
array([[32, 37, 38],
      [62, 67, 68],
      [92, 97, 98]])
```

Numpy's rules of broadcasting are your friend (and so much better than matlab)...

HTH