# numpy array slicing intersection of rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I need to slice a numpy array so that I obtain an array that corresponds to the dark green areas:
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82on7.png)

The green area is the intersection of multiple ranges in the columns and the rows. 
I thought of something like:

`M[[1:3,5:7],[1:3,5:7]]=np.zeros(4,4)`

But it doesn't work. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: How many matrices do you want as a result ? One for each intersection or a single one merging the small pieces in a single one ?

Comment: A single matrix, the aim is to get the slice and set it to zero or another value as I did in my code example

Comment: I would consider using a pandas dataframe. As you can see in the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) you can pass a callable to the iloc function. With this you can support custom slicing.

Comment: With this:    

M[starting_index:ending_index:step, starting_index:ending_index:step] 
you can select each corner of the inner matrices 
and then stack them together

example : x[1:9:5, 1:9:5] will give you row 1 and 6, columns 1 and 6. Do the same for same row different columns, and then for the next rows and columns. stacking them together at the end let's you build the matrix you need.

Comment: @NicolaePetridean there is deffinetly no more efficient solution? Matlab has an equivalent: M([1:2,5:6],[1:2,5:6])

Comment: i added another option as response.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer using this [matlab like array indexing with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393140/matlab-like-array-indexing-with-numpy) on stackoverflow

I added an array to do what I want. The final code is:

```
rows = np.hstack((np.arange(1,3), np.arange(5,7)))
cols = np.hstack((np.arange(1,3), np.arange(5,7)))

M[np.ix_(rc,rc)]=np.zeros(4,4)
```

There is maybe a more efficient way to define rows and cols but this works for me

Comment: np.hstack((x[[1,2,5,6], 1:3], x[[1,2,5,6], 5:7])) it works like this

I edited also my previous answer.

Does it help ?

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. It selects the right matrix but, it is imposible to assign a value to it like: np.hstack((x[[1,2,5,6], 1:3], x[[1,2,5,6], 5:7]))=np.zeros((4,4))

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to do each dark green section separately, so something like:

```
M[1:3, 5:7] = np.zeros((2,2))
```

Then repeat for the other dark green areas.

EDIT:
I think I understand a bit more what you want to do, you want to do it more dynamically, so I think something like this would work:

```
ta = slice(1, 3)
tb = slice(5, 7)
slices=[ta, tb]
slices = [(s1, s2) for s1 in slices for s2 in slices] #Gives all combinations of slices
for s in slices:
    M[s] = np.zeros((2,2))
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing so, but I am looking for a more efficient solution if it exists because I will scale this up and it will not be necessarily np.zeros() the matrix assigned but an already defined matrix .

Comment: Okay I see, you could use slices? (I've edited the answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE actually it works like this:**

```
np.hstack((x[[1,2,5,6], 1:3], x[[1,2,5,6], 5:7]))
```

best option i found :

```
np.vstack((x[1:9:4, [1,2,5,6]], x[2:9:4, [1,2,5,6]]))
```

but then you would still have to inter exchange lines

Comment: I think I managed to do it. I have posted it as an answer as well